# Read data from fixed with format files without header

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas how to create data frame below mentioned

Input file

```
01 Jeff Thomoson   000 11-28-2018 Payments  2,400    Wire transfer
01 Jeff Thomoson   000 11-29-2018 Interest    100    account
01 Paul Simson     000 11-12-2018 Payments  1,000    Wire transfer
01 Paul Simson     000 11-18-2018 Payments    140    net banking
01 John Sans       000 11-28-2018 Payments    300    cheque
```

Output file

```
TR  USER NAME    TR Mode  Date       Narration Amt   Mode
01 Jeff Thomoson 000      11-28-2018 Payments  2,400 Wire transfer
01 Jeff Thomoson 000      11-29-2018 Interest  100   account
01 Paul Simson   000      11-12-2018 Payments  1000  Wire transfer
01 Paul Simson   000      11-18-2018 Payments  140   Net banking
01 John Sans     000      11-28-2018 Payments  300   cheque
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. But start by reading about `pd.read_fwf()`. It's the function that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dyz has it. What you need to use is `pd.read_fwf`. For your sample data, this works out-of-box:

```
names = ['TR', 'USER NAME', 'TR Mode', 'Date', 'Narration', 'Amt', 'Mode']
pd.read_fwf(file, header=None, names=names)

     TR USER NAME  TR Mode        Date Narration    Amt           Mode
1  Jeff  Thomoson        0  11-28-2018  Payments  2,400  Wire transfer
1  Jeff  Thomoson        0  11-29-2018  Interest    100        account
1  Paul    Simson        0  11-12-2018  Payments  1,000  Wire transfer
1  Paul    Simson        0  11-18-2018  Payments    140    net banking
1  John      Sans        0  11-28-2018  Payments    300         cheque
```

You may need to muck around a bit with the widths if you still have parsing errors.